# HTML <meta> tag and squid

Tags: html, caching, meta-tags, squid, pragma

Does the HTML  tag:

```
<META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<META http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

also instruct squid to not cache that particular page? Or is it only telling the user's browser to not cache it locally in his/her machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send it as HTTP header for squid to pick it up. It is possible that your server is smart enough and adds them into the headers, but more than likely not.